# VBA autofilter and visible cells

Tags: vba, excel, visible

here's something weird i cant figure out: 
after applying filter, and LR=2, with the following code:
Row 1 and Row 2 have values in each cell all thru A1:AH2

```
For Each a In Range("O2:O" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    debug.print a
Next a
```

instead of picking only "O2" cell the loop goes through all cells in row 1.
this is a special case as LR=2 happens very rarely in my macro.

can anyone help me figure out what's happening?
Thanks

Comment: This is bizarre. If you debug the `Range("O2:O" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address`, you probably see `$1:$2,$XX:$1048576` where "XX" is some number representing the first non-filtered row, right?

Comment: unless i'm missing something, once i do Range("O2:O" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address i get error msg "invalid use of property"   BTW i'm working with excel 2010

Comment: Just `debug.print` or `msgbox` that statement in order to see what the address is.  I'm sure you will get the "wrong" address just like I did.

Comment: debug.print produced "$A:$W,$Y:$IV"

Comment: Yeah, this is bizarre. I get similar strange range address.

Comment: It looks like this was happening because one of the columns was hidden. Once i un-hide it the code works properly. It is still bizarre that a hidden column affect it but at least i can work around it.